# Real time Database of Firebase not working from android studio i can't able to upload on it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, rules

I have already fix the read and right rules on realtime database of firebase still i am unable to read and write on it.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

And i have also tried this :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Firebase Storage Rule:

```
    rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Firebase Storage Rule is Working Correctly because the image gets uploaded and onSuccessListener get called.

The Code Which i am using to setValue on database is shown below and
I have already defined references as :

```
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Events_Details");
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events_Details");

    private void uploadUserInformationToDatabase() {
        progressDialog.show();
        if (image_uri != null) {

            //this will create a big_number.jpg and when we call .child this means we are
            //going to add something inside Events_Images Directory
            StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(image_uri));

            uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(image_uri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            //Now we need to get the url of the image that you have uploaded.
                            Task<Uri> uri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                            while (!uri.isComplete());
                            String url = uri.getResult().toString();
                            createUserEvent.setImageUrl(url);

                            //now we will save this object in our database
                            String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                            databaseReference.child(uploadId)
                                             .setValue(createUserEvent);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            Toast.makeText(context, "Event Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

        } else {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(context, "No File Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Toast for Event Created Successfully displays every time and image also gets uploaded to storage but the object doesn't save on realtime database. And CreateUserEvent is just a class, the object of which i want to save to realtime database along with the image which i will upload to storage. The image always get success in uploading on firebase storage and after it onSuccess function gets called and inside onSuccess function i have written Code for object to save on realtime database but that doesn't work.Please help me to solve it i have already wasted 2 days of mine but can't able to fix this problem.
[image]

Comment: https://status.firebase.google.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok......I have tried your code. Below is the modified function:

`databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`

```
private void uploadUserInformationToDatabase() {
        progressDialog.show();

        if (image_uri != null) {

            //this will create a big_number.jpg and when we call .child this means we are
            //going to add something inside Events_Images Directory
            StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(image_uri));

            //now we will store our image file in firebase and check for success and failure events
            //And we store the reference of current process in this uploadtask variable which helps us
            //when user clicks on upload button multiple time, so when he clicks one time uploadTask will
            //take  the reference and when the upload running and the user clicks the upload button another
            //time then we put a check if uploadTask is null or not. it is null then this means no task is
            //running else we don't upload. This check you put above in upload onlicklisterner.


            uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(image_uri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

//                            lets create the object with name and url of the image and save this object into our database.
//                            String name_of_event = file_name.getText().toString().trim();
//                            String url_of_image = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
//                            Upload upload = new Upload(name_of_event, url_of_image);



                            //Now you just need to get the url of the image that you have uploaded.

                            Task<Uri> uri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                            while (!uri.isComplete()) ;
                            String url = uri.getResult().toString();
                            createUserEvent.setImageUrl(url);

                            //now we will save this object in our database
                            String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Going To Save Object To Firebase");
                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: UPLOAD ID : "+uploadId);

                            databaseReference.child("Event Details").child(uploadId).setValue(createUserEvent).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to upload data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(context, "No File Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I am getting success while uploading to database. Please check your database now.

Comment: I have added my storage rule.

Comment: Is uploadId is coming from firebase? Test it via a toast.@shivanshshrivastava

Comment: And please put a screenshot of your database. I think the passing parameter in the getReference() is causing the problem. Please provide a screenshot of the database.

Comment: i have added the screenshot.The onSuccessListener for databaseReference i don't how to use it. I will google it and soon providing you console log with that.The Upload id i have shown on logcat .

Comment: Your parameter in the getReference() is causing the problem.

Comment: try this.```databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();```and then add ```databaseReference.child("Events_Details").child(uploadId).setValue(createUserEvent);``` and please let me know the result.

Comment: Which rule should i specify, the first one or second one out of those which i specified in my issue for realtime database.

Comment: 2nd one is better

Comment: ok...please include the username and password to log in. I need to debug the app.

Comment: And any additional information is needed then you can email at: amimulahsan7@gmail.com

Comment: Ok, now the code is ready on github you can clone and then fix.
[link]https://github.com/Shivansh1980/iCLOCK
Username and Password not required you can sign in using google.

Comment: please provide login username and password.

Comment: Event section still not showing the List of events? What's the error in that ?

Comment: Its reading problem from firebase. Check your function that will read from the firebase. There might be an error on that function.

Answer (score 0):

StorageReference filepath=storageReference.child("Blogimage").child(System.currentTimeMillis()+ "." +getFileEXt(imageuri));
//uploadTask=filepath.putFile(imageuri);

```
               filepath.putFile(imageuri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                     // String downlod = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                       if (taskSnapshot.getMetadata() != null) {
                           if (taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference() != null) {
                               Task<Uri> result = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                               result.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                       String imageUrl = uri.toString();
                                       DatabaseReference newpost=databaseReference.push();
                                       Map<String , String > profile =new HashMap<>();
                                       profile.put("name",name);
                                       profile.put("prof",prof);
                                       profile.put("location",location);
                                       profile.put("email",mail);
                                       profile.put("web",web);
                                       profile.put("uid",user.getUid());
                                       profile.put("url",imageUrl);

                                       allUserMember.setName(name);
                                       allUserMember.setUid(auth.getUid());

                                       allUserMember.setProf(prof);
                                       allUserMember.setLocation(location);

                                       allUserMember.setUrl(imageUrl);
                                       newpost.setValue(profile);
                                       newpost.child(user.getUid()).setValue(allUserMember);
                                       documentReference.set(profile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                                               Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Image uplode",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                               pd.dismiss();
                                               Toast.makeText(CreateProfile1.this, "it work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                           }
                                       });
                                       //createNewPost(imageUrl);
                                   }
                               });
                           }
                       }
```